# Local asp.net restart with Oauth--provider logged in but session lost

Tags: asp.net, session, dotnetopenauth

I'm developing a dropbox asp.net application, and it's working at least in localhost mode. But I'm facing a problem that I hope is only during localhost testing and won't (CAN NOT) occur in production. It's a bit difficult to explain so I will describe it in steps.

1) The browser is not running and I start the "logged in membership target page" in Debugger. It asks dropbox for login and permission. At this time, in my Oauth derived class, I store my drop box object with access token and secret in a session variable.

2) In my actual "logged in" page, I extract the object from the session and start using dropbox and it works fine.

3) Now suppose I stop debugging from Visual Studio 2012. Make some modifications to the code. Now I start again. This time the browser is already logged in to dropbox and the target page is displayed logged in. I see no "Allow" prompt from dropbox. But there is no session variable now to extract my drop box object because this is a new session. But for dropbox it is the already logged in session.

I want to confirm that this situation can only occur during localhost running and can not occur in real production app because it will always go from a web site in the browser which will have its own session. Or can it occur? What is the solution in that case.

Another doubt is, why doesn't dropbox ask for Allow prompt next time if the browser is open but the app is starting a new session. It must be getting the same access token and secret from somewhere. From where?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workable solution. If I find that the session has been lost, I execute the following code and it logs off the user. Even if the situation might occur only in my local testing, this takes care of it.

```
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Redirect("/");
                return;
```